# Android ListFragment addfooterview()

Tags: android

I have been attempting to add a footer button to the end of my list. My list is working appropriately however I cannot figure out why I cannot add the footer view.
 My end goal is to inflate the view and add a footer button via xml however I need to get this to work at least first.

```
public void onActivityCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources for users inventory into Array 
    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    // Binding Array to ListAdapter        
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.inventory_list, R.id.label, adobe_products);

    // LoadMore button
    Button btnScan = new Button(getActivity());
    btnScan.setText("Scan Inventory");

    // Adding Load More button to list view at bottom
    lv.addFooterView(btnScan); 

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item 
          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          //Intent i = new Intent(PhotosFragment.this, InventoryItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          //i.putExtra("product", product);
          //startActivity(i);
      }
    });

    btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Starting a new async task
            //Intent send_Scan=new Intent(PhotosFragment.this, ScanActivity.class);
            //PhotosFragment.this.startActivity(send_Scan);
        }
    });
}
```

Edit :
    When running the application it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop. Consistently loading.

Comment: Your code seems appropriate - what is happening when you run the code? Do you get an exception or?

Comment: The method surrounding the code seems to be wrong. There are no method with the signature `public void onActivityCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` for a `Fragment` - the signature should be `public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` - so you're code is never called I presume?

Comment: If your application is stuck in an infinite loop, it's probably not because of the code above. Figure out where this infinite loop is and you'll probably solve your issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can't get `ListView` in `onCreateView`.

Use in `onStart()`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    getListView().addFooterView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.ly_footer_acreditacao, null));
}
```